# Simple example with Preact is firing twice on useState

Tags: javascript, preact

I have a tiny Preact component where I want to toggle the visibility of a div, but it is not working as expected. The following recreates the issue:

```
import { h, render } from 'preact';
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks';

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  function toggle() {
    console.log('toggle');
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  console.log(isOpen);

  if (isOpen) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={toggle}>Close</div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div onClick={toggle}>Open</div>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.body);
```

But it doesn't work like I would expect. The console output is the following:

```
true
toggle
false
toggle
true
```

First two lines are from initial rendering. All of the rest happens when I click Close. I would expect Close to change to Open, and the console output to be the following when I click Close:

```
toggle
false
```

I use this to build:

```
esbuild ./tmp.tsx --bundle --watch --minify --outdir=./ --jsx-factory=h --jsx-fragment=Fragment
```

and the html is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script async src="tmp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is going on here?

---- EDIT ----

I played around a bit with different html structure and got really weird behaviour.

1. With the following, the first click works as expected, but subsequent clicks trigger twice.

```
  if (isOpen) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={toggle}>Close</div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div onClick={toggle}>Open</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

2. This however works as expected:

```
  if (isOpen) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={toggle}>Close</div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={toggle}>Open</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Looks like a serious bug to me. I will file an issue on their repo and then try another mini-react alternative.

Comment: No, it is toggling back to true, after just one click. So just one click makes it first go false then go true.

Comment: Ah, apologies. Must've read that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this can be solved by adding keys (i.e. ) to the divs.